# jQuery Datatables stop sort on tfoot elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I've been looking over the API's and searching there forums, but I can't find anything as of yet. Right now what I have is a standard table

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
     <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

quick hand typed rendition. Anyway.. when I click on the elements in the thead to have it sort, the stuff in the tfoot sorts with the stuff in the tbody. In a sense negating the needs I'd want to have a tfoot for.

So my overall question is, is there a way to exclude the tfoot from being included in the sort?

datatable settings:

```
 $('#'+tableID).dataTable(
                {
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": true,
                    "sScrollY": tableY+"px",
                    "bScrollCollapse": true,
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sInfo": "Showing _END_ Events."
                    },
                    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                    "aoColumns": [
                         null,
                         null,
                         null,
                         null
                       ]
                });
```

Comment: Add your script code too, please.

Comment: added my datatable call.

Comment: Off topic a bit, but you should place your `tfoot` before the `tbody`.

Comment: actually in a recent change not shown here I have tried that, still it sorts with the tbody

Comment: @chris: I just meant in general. It's a requirement of the spec so that browsers can render the `tfoot` without needing to wait for the all of the `tbody` rows. Sorry, it was just an off-topic note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard [examples](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html) from the website for DataTables don't have the problem you describe; i.e., the footer isn't part of the sorting.

I've attempted to fork one of the examples and use (most) of the code you offered as a sample, with only a few modifications. The footer is not part of the sorting.

http://live.datatables.net/uyanul/edit#javascript,html,live

Maybe there is a piece of code causing this issue that wasn't part of your original question?

Comment: not sure, everything appears to be the same not noticing the tweaks you made, less they are that minor, however. Your right there could be something somewhere. Effecting it that Im not seeing at the moment.

Comment: Upon further inspection.. I realized what should have been in my tfoot, wasn't. It was appending to the tbody and getting mixed up in the sort there of. Fixing the problem causing it to go in the body and not the foot, fixed the problem overall. Don't think I would have paid mind to that for a while to come if it wasn't your answer that got me thinking. Thank you.